# Making 24 - Most Complicated Way

Tags: mathematics

In this question, I am asking you to get to 24 in the most complicated way using the numbers below.

[image]

One way to solve this is (9 x 8)  / ( 6 / 2 ) = 24. But this is an easy way.

I am looking for the most **complicated** way of getting to 24. The person scoring the highest amount of *complicated points* wins.

**Generic rules for complicated**

there are no strict rules that apply for 'complicated' answers, as the community will vote for the most complicated answer. However the following is generally encouraged:

- getting to higher numbers within your equation wins you more 'complicated points' (e.g I got to a maximum of 72 in the above equation)
- use of non-common operators  (factorials, square roots, absolute signs) is deemed more complicated than common operators

**Other Rules**

- you are allowed to rearrange the numbers on the left hand side to get to 24
- you are allowed to combine numbers if you deem it more complicated
- you are only allowed to use each number once

Comment: Should the numbers be in order?

Comment: @KritixiLithos -  "you are allowed to rearrange the numbers on the left hand side to get to 24"

Comment: @randal'thor Sorry, my bad...

Comment: This question seems to be too broad in that the answer is chosen instead of found, so I have voted to close it.

Comment: Can we use a number more than once?

Comment: @AggieKidd - no you can't use a number more than once. I will add it to the rules. But thought this would have been clear enough.

Comment: @MarkN - use of variables is prohibited

Comment: @MarkN I was going to ask why you dislike your own question, but then I saw the N!

Comment: Many great answers - Aggie / randal'thor / Mark N to name a few, I would love to see which answer OP approves!

Comment: This reminds me a lot of [code bowling](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) on PPCG, which [didn't work out well](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/should-we-kill-code-bowling).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One that is mathematically precise (rounding answers are such cop-outs! (p.s. I upvoted them in any case))

Using the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\zeta$ 
, the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) $\text{sgn}$, the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma$ , the [sigma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) $\sigma_0$  and the [negation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Negation)

$$\begin{align}
24 & =\frac{\frac{\text{sgn}(2)}{-\zeta(-9)}}{\Gamma(\sigma_{0}(8))+\zeta(\zeta(-6))}\\
& =\frac{\frac{1}{-1/-132}}{\Gamma(4)+\zeta(0)}\\
& =\frac{132}{6-0.5}\\
& =\frac{132}{5.5}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is quite complicated.

Comment: This is crazy complicated! I voted for this being the most complicated answer

Answer (score 18):

How about:

> $\sum_{8}^{9} (6 * 2) = 24$

A little bit of notation mutilation, but hey...

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant!

Comment: What function does the sigma have? I know it means "sum of" but sum of what numbers?

Comment: Gotta love the genius in this equation

Comment: @KritixiLithos Generally you would insert numbers into the formula, but since there is no variable to place them into, you would simply run add up the numbers for each value in the range of the sumation.

Comment: @AggieKidd With your avatar, I imagine you as someone who does nothing but answer various StackExchange questions with clever uses of sum expressions.

Comment: Hey, I found another one: $\sum_6^8(9-\Gamma(2))=24$. Nobody use it XD

Answer (score 14):

How about this?

> $\Big\lceil\frac{8!}{9!}\Big\rceil\times(6-2)!=24$

Comment: I am just curious, what are the big bracket-like symbols which are around 8!/9! called and what function do they do?

Comment: @KritixiLithos They're called *ceiling* symbols. $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$ (so the ceiling of 3.7 is 4 and the ceiling of 4 is also 4).

Comment: Aah, I see. Now I get the answer, thank you.

Comment: Wow - took me a while to actually to just understand this complicated answer. Learnt something new today.

Comment: @Rand isn't it the smallest integer function?

Answer (score 13):

Here's one with a number that goes *really* big:

$$\lceil{\ln(9^{(8 + 2)} \times 6)}\rceil = 24$$

Comment: It's the ceiling function, since obviously the natural log can't be met precisely.

Answer (score 9):

I'm fairly certain I'm going to terribly mess up the markup on this, but here goes:

> $\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\dfrac{(8+2)!}{\sqrt[\sqrt{\sqrt{6!}}]{9!}}}}\right\rceil=24$

Answer (score 8):

> (λn.λf.λx.n (λg.λh.h (g f)) (λu.x) (λu.u)) π<sup>2</sup>$(6*89)$

Explanation:

> π<sup>2</sup> is the [Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) nested twice, and the rest is apparently the simplest way to express the predecessor function in lambda calculus. So we multiply 6 by 89 (534), count the number of primes less than or equal to it (99), count the number of primes less than or equal to *that* (25), then subtract 1 (24).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a little bit less complicated than the others

> $\sqrt[\sqrt{9}]{8} * 6 * 2 = \sqrt[3]{8} * 6 * 2 = 2 *6 * 2 = 24$

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Added what will surely win as the "highest number" prize and dropped the spoiler tags as they don't seem necessary with this question.

---

How about an infinite score using an infinite number of square roots and, just for fun, factorials? Do you count complication based on the number of different terms used or just the number used in total?

$$\left[\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{9}}}}}}\right)!!!\ldots!!!\right]\times8\times6\div2=1\times8\times6\div2=24$$

Or, just to claim the "highest number" prize using [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation):

$$\left\lfloor{
\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots m \ldots\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{
9 \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\ldots n \ldots\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 8
}}}}}}
}\right\rfloor
\times\frac{6!!}{2}=0$$

where $n$ is as large as needed to have the highest number and $m$ is as large as needed so that the floor function evaluates to $1$. I am not mathematical enough to *prove* that up-arrow notation will grow faster than the double factorial method proposed by Rodolvertice but I am fairly sure that it does so quite easily.

(Note that the $6!!$ is the double factorial and $6!!=48$)

Comment: @grgarside Thanks for the additional MathJax. I keep forgetting about the formatting that helps make it prettier.

Answer (score 4):

Claims both the infinite operators score and the largest number score.

$n!!$ is the double factorial. There is no factorial used here, only double factorials.

$$\cfrac{6!!}{2!!!!\ldots\ldots!!!!}-{\left\lfloor{\cfrac{8!!!!... ...!!!!}{9!!!!... ...!!!!}}\right\rfloor}=24$$

The number $2$ can have an infinite number of factorials (double or single) applied to it and it will still be $2$.

$$\cfrac{6!!}{2!!}=24$$

this is because $6!!=48$, then dividing that by $2$ results in $24$, and $2=2!=2!!=2!!!\dots!!!$

$$\left\lfloor{\frac{8!!!!\dots n\dots!!!!}{9!!!!\dots n\dots!!!!}}\right\rfloor=0$$

Subtracting $0$ does nothing. n (the number of double factorials) can be very VERY large but not infinite, and it will still evaluate to $0$. Just enough so that it is more than the largest number here.

Comment: Where could I learn to use MathJax? My answers never look pretty...

Comment: I picked up after a few weeks here.

Comment: Thanks! I assume I can learn by pressing the edit button on posts to see the source? Or is there an easier way that is less error prone?

Comment: That's about the only way to do it! You can also make equations at http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php (LaTeX friendly)

Comment: @Rodolvertice Also see this [this Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks! I edited it to make it prettier :) Can't get the floor to extend to cover the entire fraction though.

Comment: It's always funny to me when math gets so crazy it stops looking like math

Comment: @zfrisch Yes, and the amount of ambiguities is also astonishing (Factorial is !, double factorial is !!, but ${(x!)!}\neq{x!!}$, but ! only applies to integers, you need the Gamma function to get to those pesky decimals... and symbols are used for multiple different things.) I've always thought of making a 'constructed' math language, accompanied with a constructed spoken and written language, as well as a computer programming language to go with it. But its time consuming and difficult.

Comment: @Rodolvertice For the floor bracket problem: use \left\lfloor and \right\rfloor to make them scale.

Comment: @Rodolvertice Take a look at the [Mathjax Guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/222802) on Math Meta

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that looks complicated...but really isn't:

> $\phi$ - The Golden ratio
> $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(-(\sqrt{9-8+e^{\pi\cdot i}} \times \sinh(f'(\phi)))^3) \ \mathrm dx + (6\cdot2!)$

Comment: What are $f$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Sheez that looks complicated

Comment: @randal'thor, this was modified from my troll bridge answer [they don't really matter].... ;)

Comment: This answer's invalid since it uses $e$ and $\pi$ too many times.

Comment: @JoeZ. You can _never_ have too much $\pi e$ (pi-e `;)`).

Comment: @JoeZ. Fixed it for the people that aren't so electric for pi.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one

> $(6 << 2) + \Big\lfloor\frac{8}{9}\Big\rfloor=24$

Comment: Bit-shifting, eh? Why don't you just multiply by $9 - 8$ at the end, rather than using the floor expression to just reduce things?

Comment: I don't understand this one. What does the << operation mean?

Comment: @JoeZ Because I wanted to complicate things more than necessary, per the request of this question.

Comment: @randal'thor It's a bit shift operator. Basically, the bits (binary representation) for 6 are $0000 0110$. This shifts the bits two to the left, $0001 1000$, which is 24 in decimal.

Comment: In other words $n<<k = n \cdot 2^k$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(\frac {8}{2} x^\sqrt9+ 6!x) = 24
$$

Comment: Arguably the $^3$ are numbers though.

Comment: How about that? the $$ \frac{d^3}{dx^3} $$ is notation so i dont think it should count

Comment: @Tim All math writing is notation. The 3 indicates 3rd derivative just as 3 by itself indicates the third successor of 0.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few contributions. $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Gamma_function); $x!!$ is the [double factorial](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573418); $\text{Res}$ is the residue of a function (I found the one for $\Gamma$ on the first link); $\phi$ is the [Totient Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html).

## 1

### Equation

$$\tag{1}\frac{\frac{9!}{\Gamma(8)}}{\frac62}$$
or
$$\tag{1b}(9!/\Gamma(8))/(6/2)$$

### Explanation

$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$
$$\begin{align}(9!/\Gamma(8)/(6/2))&=24\\
(9!/7!)/(6/2)&=\\
(72)/(3)&=\\
24&=
\end{align}$$
BONUS: $(1)$ maintains order.

## 2

### Equation

$$\tag{2}\Gamma(9+6-(8+2!))$$

### Explanation

$$\begin{align}\Gamma(9+6-(8+2!))&=24\\\Gamma(15-(8+2))&=\\\Gamma(5)&=\\4!&=\\24&=\end{align}$$

## 3

If you allow $n^{-1}$ as an operation and not a number:

### Equation

$$\tag{3}-\text{Res}(\Gamma,-8/2)^{-1}+\left\lfloor\text{Res}(\Gamma,-9/6!)^{-1}\right\rfloor$$

### Explanation

$$\text{Res}(\Gamma,-n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$
$$-\text{Res}(\Gamma,-8/2)^{-1}=-\text{Res}(\Gamma,-4)^{-1}=-\frac{-1}{4!}^{-1}=-\frac{-1}{24}^{-1}=--24=24$$
Of course, $0\lt\Gamma(9/6!)^-1\lt1$, so it becomes $0$ in the floor bit. Thus, the answer is $24$.

## 4

### Equation

$$\tag{4}\phi(9+8)+6+2$$

### Explanation

$$\phi(9+8)=\phi(17)=16$$
[check here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EulerPhi[9%2B8])
$$16+6+2=22+2=24$$

Answer (score 1):

Does this involve big enough numbers for you?

> I define the operation $*$ on pairs of integers in such a way that $9*8$ is a googolplex and $6*2$ is 24 times a googolplex. Then $\frac{6*2}{9*8}=24$.

Comment: points for getting the highest number.

Comment: -1 for being too arbitrary in the "creativity" involved.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lfloor\tan(\cos(\sin\lceil(\sqrt{8})^{[\frac{d}{dx}(-9x)]}\rceil))\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{6!}-2\rfloor$$

Where $x$ is an arbitrary number.

Comment: Is using a variable "x" allowed?